# Adsense ad with a link to a Google+ Page

Tags: google-adsense

I'm planning to buy an adspace on a specific website through Google Adsense, to link to a Google+ Business Page from it.
I've seen ads with a "+1 button" in it, is a link to Google+ Page possible too?

The html link would look like this:

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/1234567890" rel="publisher">Follow Company</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can connect your Google+ Page to your AdWords campaigns, so, when you buy an adspace your ads will show the link to your page and your followers in your Google+ page.

You can read about "Show ads with your Google+ page endorsements" here: https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1722132?hl=en-GB

Answer (score -1):

yes you can link to G+ from google adsense, I don't see any issue with it.